# Index error when trying to access list element

Tags: python, csv, indexing

So I have a text document in csv style, like this:

```
Line number,1  
1,K1,O1,L1,L2,L3  
2,K2,O2,L2,L3  
3,K3,O3,L1,L3  
4,K4,O4,L2
```

I want to check if the number in the first line, after "Line number", is equal to the first element in one of the following lines. In this case this number can be 1, 2, 3 or 4.

My code is as follows:

```
import csv

lineNumber = 0

with open('B.txt', 'r') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

    for row in reader:
        if "Line Number" in row[0]:
            lineNumber = int(row[1]) <- not sure about this syntax btw
            print("Is equal")
            break
```

I end up with this error:

```
if "Line Number" in row[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Everything with row[n] seems to give an error.

Comment: [How to debug small programs (#3)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 improvements to your code:

1. Compare objects of the same type, e.g. `int` with `int`.
2. Use `next(reader)` to extract the first row before your `for` loop.

This is one way you can refactor your logic:

```
import csv

with open('B.txt', 'r') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

    headers = next(reader)
    lineNumber = int(headers[1])

    for row in reader:
        if int(row[0]) == lineNumber:
            print("Is equal")
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
lineNumber = 0
with open('test', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'Line number':
            lineNumber = row[1]
        else:
            if row[0] == lineNumber:
            print 'isEqual for row ',row
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example csv file lists `'Line number,1'` - you test for `'Line Number'` - look at the capitalization of ***n**umber* vs ***N**umber*.

[minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that creates the file and implements your logic:

```
import csv

t= """Line number,1
1,K1,O1,L1,L2,L3
2,K2,O2,L2,L3
3,K3,O3,L1,L3
4,K4,O4,L2
"""

# create file
fn = "B.txt"
with open(fn,"w") as f:
    f.write(t)

# parse file 
lineNumber = 0
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader: 
        if "Line number" in row[0]:  # fixed capitalization
            lineNumber = row[1]      # no need to make it an int, str compare is fine 
        elif row[0] == lineNumber:
            print("Is equal", row)
            break
```

Comment: Well, that was a stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing that out to me. And you're totally right, lineNumber = row[1] not row[0].